# is alfresco the right tool for search?

Tags: search, solr, alfresco

I'm in a training in a company, they have given me a project of choosing a search engine that will help all the employees find their documents or any information they need.

This search engine should index and allow search in:

- The company's Intranet(wiki...)
- The Internet
- SVN Repository
- and most importantly the disk shared on the network

After a long search, I found that Alfresco has a functionnality of a search engine but not only it also offers documents management, records management and so on. I found that alfresco uses Solr for the search.

My question is : Is Alfresco the right tool for search ?

Comment: Why would you use a CMS to implement search?

Comment: I can't seem to find another existing tool. They have advised me to use that's what's confusing but it doesn't seem right to me too a CMS only for search isn't right. Can only solr make the deal?

Comment: absolutely, solr or elasticsearch would be better options. You would need to implement some ways to crawl or feed documents to the search server, but that would be it. Alfresco doesn't seem the right tool from the requirements that you posted.

Comment: I'm lost for two weeks now, I just need to focus on a tool to start the project. I have tried alfresco, its search functionaity is pretty good but I'm confused why using all alfresco only for search!! Please can anyone just guide me, I've looked for 2 weeks now and I'm wasting time!

Comment: Thx a lot skuro for ur help I will try understing solr and I will try elasticsearch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you question is too specific. We could just answer: Yes or No.

When abstracting the question to

- [What tools are out there for an Intranet search engine across a diverse toolset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382603/what-tools-are-out-there-for-an-intranet-search-engine-across-a-diverse-toolset)
- or just googling for "intranet search open source"

You will find much more.

- Solr + Nutch is an option
- probably you will also require [Apache ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html#What+Is+Apache+ManifoldCF?)
- if you want those wrapped up, you maybe better of with [OpenESP](http://openesn.net/openesp.html)

Comment: Thx a lot cheffe for ur answer! I have done some research about integrating solr+ manifoldCF or solr+nutch, found some tools that wrap up all of these what do u recommand a tool that wraps up everything(lucidworks, datafari). Or integrating them myself ?

Comment: That depends, are you there just for a short time and will leave that pice of software behind you? In that case I would favour something that wraps it up for you, since it will be easier to maintain.

Comment: actually it's a six months training, It's something they need so If i use and it works they will keep it. But since it's 6 months, I wanna do this and move on to another project. isn't 6 months too much for this project?

Comment: That depends :) if you want to re-invent something like OpenESP six months is too few ...

Comment: Thx cheffe :) I didn't know that, I'm pretty new to all this. So OpenESP is the best tool for this? is there enough documentation on it ?

Comment: Documentation is available https://github.com/openesp/openesp/tree/master/documentation - if it is _the_ best I cannot tell. But not a bad one.